# Function creating in Lua

Tags: function, lua, coronasdk

When I create the function by assigning ,"if" condition doesn't work but when I do create the function like in second example below, it works. Can you tell me why?

Not working:

```
local start=os.time()

local countDown = function(event)
   if((os.time()-start)==3) then
      Runtime: removeEventListener("enterFrame", countDown)
   end
   print(os.time()-start)
end

Runtime:addEventListener("enterFrame", countDown)
```

Working:

```
local start=os.time()

local function countDown(event)
   if((os.time()-start)==3) then
      Runtime: removeEventListener("enterFrame", countDown)
   end
   print(os.time()-start)
end

Runtime:addEventListener("enterFrame", countDown)
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

That's because when you do `local countDown = ...`, the `countDown` variable *doesn't exist* until *after* the `...` part has been executed. So your function will access a *global* variable, not the local one that doesn't exist yet.

Note that Lua converts `local function countDown ...` into the following:

```
local countDown
countDown = function ...
```